# Why do we see black when we close our eyelids?

Tags: human-eye, skin, pigmentation

Why do we usually see black when we close our eyelids assuming there is no strong light source outside?

I realize we never really stop seeing as long as our eyes are healthy but based on assumption I would have assumed that the back of the eyelids would be the same as the front and this could be a range of skin colors other than black.

Is it because most times not enough light is being reflected off the back to show the color?

Comment: This is easily answered by first washing your hands, then standing in front of a mirror, pulling an eyelid away from the eye, then folding it to look at the underside. Hint: it's not black.

Comment: Hah! That sounds painful and it does not answer the question the in actual text of the post which is why we see black when we close our eyelids. I will retitle the question. Sorry.

Comment: The question is actually not a question of biology but of the physics of light. Absence of light is black. Closing your eyelids prevent the light to reach your eyes, so you see black. Even if the interior of your eyelids were snow white, you would still see black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the cone cell in the eye allows you to see different colors, and it only function in an illuminated environment, and function less in a less illuminated area.
 when your eyes is closed totally obstruct the entrance of incident ray from the outside thereby causing only the rod cell to be functioning .then the only thing you can observe is total darkness.

Comment: can you add a reference for your answer?